# Is it possible to do a Google/Yahoo/Bing search restricted to the "description" meta data?

Tags: web-services, search, web-applications, search-engine

I'm working on a project that would be greatly optimized if I am able to restrict a Google, Yahoo or Bing/Live search to just the < meta content="xyz" name="description" /> tag. I read all the help pages and api docs and can't seem to find a way to do it, and I thought I'd give it a shot here on Stack Overflow.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the big 3 support this sort of limitation. I tried a similar search a while back limited to tags, but had no luck.

If you are trying to find web pages that match a description exactly, **here is a solution**.

Find a major website that reports "website stats" for third parties.

Example www.sitebrain.com

Then use the site: operator in google to search that site for a list of pages that report on sites including your target descriptions.

Example **site:statbrain.com + Get product information, support, and news from Microsoft.**

The resulting Google results will be a list of pages all matching the description.